# Origin of 2 Marthas from Earth2

Tags: plot-explanation, dark

I've not been able to get the origin of the 2 Marthas at the end of Netflix's Dark.

I did get to see the origin of 2 Jonas's during Earth1's apocalypse, where Jonas is seen going back to the basement and the second one created by Earth2's Martha coming and rescuing him to take him to Earth2.

Similarly where did 2 Marthas come from?
We know that Earth1's Martha died early and was killed by Adam himself at the begining of 1st apocalypse, Just before creating the loop for 2 Adams.
And Earth2's Martha was seen being killed by Adam again with some help of the God particle moments before Claudia could arrive with the solution at the last episode of season 3.

Also I do remember that this Martha was caged by Adam, that's when I first remember seeing her.

Just need to know which episode did this loop of 2 Marthas happen?
Did I miss something or was not shown at all?!

Answer (score 1):

What you missed can be found in Season 3 Episode 7, which is the episode that ties up most of the loose ends.  (Look for the bolded parenthetical below.) In any case, the multiple versions of Earth 1’s Jonas are actually caused by the multiple versions of Earth 2’s Martha.  Except there are three versions of each, not two as you suggested.

For convenience, I’ll label the three timelines as A, B, and C.  And throughout when I talk about Jonas and Martha I mean Earth 1’s Jonas and Earth 2’s Martha.

- Timeline A: Right before the apocalypse Martha A brings Jonas A to Earth 2.  Jonas A is ultimately killed by Martha B.  Martha A is ultimately killed using the God Particle by the elderly Jonas B, who goes by the name Adam.
- Timeline B: Right before the apocalypse Bartosz B tells Martha B not to go into the house, and instead come with him to see Eve.  **(This was shown in Season 3 Episode 7.)** On Eve’s instructions Martha B shoots Jonas A and then grows up to become Eve.  Jonas B survives the apocalypse alone in the basement, and then grows up to become Adam.
- Timeline C: Right before the apocalypse Adam takes Jonas C to Earth 2.  Jonas C takes Martha C away before adult Magnus C and Franzisca C gan get to her, and then Jonas C and Martha C go to the Origin World to prevent it from splitting into Earth 1 and Earth 2.

And by the way, the thing that allows these multiple timelines to coexist in a quantum superposition is that during the Apocalypse, time stands still for a moment.  Eve exploits that moment to create new timelines.

Comment: In timeline A, how did Adam get hold of Martha A to kill her by the God particle??

Comment: @JoshuaAmaral Adam doesn’t need to get hold of her, she comes to him. Something that happens in both timeline A and timeline B is that when Martha is trying to stop the Earth 2 Apocalypse, she’s approached by an adult Magnus and Franciska who recruit her into working for Adam. It’s just that in timeline B Bartosz convinces her to switch sides from Adam to Eve. In timeline A she sticks with Adam, so per Adam’s orders she takes Jonas to Earth 2, then meets the adult Jonas in the 1800’s, then voluntarily goes to Adam in the future, where to her surprise he puts her in a cage and kills her.

Comment: Great answer. Just that they are not different timelines. They are different instances of Jonas and Martha in the same timeline. None of the other people are replicated. Jonas and Martha are multiple thanks to Quantum Entanglement within the confines of one timeline.

Comment: @MovieMe The explanation given in the show is that they are multiple entangled timelines, not one timeline with multiple people. But yes, the show’s explanation doesn’t fully make sense, but I think that’s a reflection of the fact that nothing that violates the Novikov self-consistency principle fully makes sense. In any case it’s not just Jonas and Martha who take different actions, Bartosz also seems to take different actions in timelines A and B. In timeline B he tells Martha not to go into Jonas’ house, whereas in timeline A he doesn’t tell her that. I’m not sure what the reason is though.

Comment: The show explains that there are multiple entangle events (and copies of people as a result) not entangled timelines. If there were multiple entangled timelines then there would be copies of everyone. You're right about Bartoz, there would need to be two. Not just that two Adams and Eves (one where he kills Eve and the other where he doesn't). I agree with you, at one point the show used QE and gave birth to far too many issues.